# Django not working with supervisor, getting [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: django, supervisord, daphne

I have made a server using Django REST framework and Django channels but I am unable to configure supervisor to run with it. My supervisor config is as follow:

```
[program:frnd_django]
socket=tcp://localhost:8000
directory=/home/coldbrewtech/frnd/backend/dating-app-backend/django-server/cbproj/
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cbproj.dev_settings
command=/home/coldbrewtech/frnd/backend/env/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers cbproj.asgi:application
stdout_logfile=/home/coldbrewtech/frnd/backend/dating-app-backend/django-server/cbproj/logs/django_out.log
stderr_logfile=/home/coldbrewtech/frnd/backend/dating-app-backend/django-server/cbproj/logs/django_err.log
numprocs=4
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=KILL
```

And the error that I am getting is as follow:

```
2019-05-21 18:03:50,111 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,121 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2019-05-21 18:03:50,125 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2019-05-21 18:03:50,130 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne1.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,131 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,132 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2019-05-21 18:03:50,133 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2019-05-21 18:03:50,134 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2019-05-21 18:03:50,145 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2019-05-21 18:03:50,154 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,158 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
2019-05-21 18:03:50,159 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2019-05-21 18:03:50,160 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2019-05-21 18:03:50,163 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
2019-05-21 18:03:50,160 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,168 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
2019-05-21 18:03:50,177 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,181 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne1.sock
2019-05-21 18:03:50,192 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
2019-05-21 18:03:50,204 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
```

I am not sure whether this is daphne issue or some supervisor issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your configuration file. Section `[program:frnd_django]` doesn't have key `socket`. Instead you need to use `[fcgi-program:frnd_django]` section that allows to configure sockets for your daphne workers. For more information check the docs [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#fcgi-program-x-section-settings).

So, those key/value pairs in your config that are not recognized are perhaps just ignored (no syntax error). And because of that supervisor doesn't create a socket for the daphne process before splitting it. Then, daphne throws an error `[Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket`. There is a note about this error in Channels docs [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#example-setups).